# protobuf protoc creating wrong header dependency path

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf 3.10
given a folder structure like this:

```
ProtocTest
-- Messages
---- Common
------ CommonFields.proto
---- Incoming
------ Incoming.proto
---- protoc.exe
```

CommonFields.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package proto.common;

enum Color
{
    None=0;
    Blue=1;
    Red=2;
    Green=3;
}
```

Incoming.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package proto.incoming;

import "Common/CommonFields.proto";

message IncomingColor
{
    int32 id = 1;
    proto.common.Color color = 2;
}
```

When i run the protoc.exe from within the Messages folder with this command:

```
../protoc.exe --cpp_out="..\Compiled" Incoming\*.proto
```

The resulting compiled class shows up in the proper location within Incoming\Compiled, but the .cc class header includes looks like this:

```
#include "Incoming/Incoming.pb.h"
```

Since the .cc and the header are in the same directory, obviously the code can't find the header. I'm at a loss on how to adjust my execution switches so that this doesn't happen. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `Compiled/Messages` to include search path for your compiler, and `#include "Incoming/Incoming.pb.h"` would work just fine.

Comment: That seems to be a bandaid and does not explain why the executable believes that the header would be in a different folder than the implementation file.

Comment: `protoc` always generates #include directives relative to the output directory. Since .proto files can import each other, and each such import translates to an #include, there must be a mechanism to refer to files in sibling directories.

Comment: I follow. As long as I add the cpp_out directory to my project include directory, then the project should be able to see all the headers as they are relevant to that top level directory.

Comment: I followed your advice, though i'm still running into an issue. I look at the pb.h file, and it's looking for Common/CommonFields.pb.h. I only had my search path go to the top-level messages. This is going to be painful if i have to point it to every subdirectory in the tree.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You ran `protoc` from `Messages` directory; the structure under `Compiled` mirrors that under `Messages`. Both `Incoming/Incoming.pb.h` and `Common/CommonFields.pb.h` are relative to `Compiled`. If you just add `Compiled` to include search path, both will be found. What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: This was a stupid mistake on my part. I did not compile the common folder. I incorrectly assumed that by building the protos that depended on it, that it would pull them in internally instead of using a #include. I compiled and it appears to work.